# Stop playing music

Tags: loops, java-me

I have app with music on start. Lenght of music is 23s, but it's playing without stopping. Music starts to play in loop **while**. How to stop looping when music lenght is over?

```
public void start() {
  try {
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/a.mid");
    midiPlayer = Manager.createPlayer(is, "audio/midi");
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }
  z = true;
  Thread t = new Thread(this);
  t.start();
}

public void stop() {
  z = false;
}

public void run() {
  Graphics g = getGraphics();
  while (z) {
    draw(g);
    inputKey();
    try {
      Thread.sleep(200);
      midiPlayer.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Player` object only plays the music once, unless you instruct it to replay. One way of telling it to reply is to call `midiPlayer.setLoopCount(10);` to have it play 10 times.
Another way of looping is to implement the `PlayerListener` and add this code:

```
public void playerUpdate(Player player, String event, Object eventData) {
  if (event.equals(PlayerListener.END_OF_MEDIA)) {
    try {
      player.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
  }
}
```

A third way of looping, which is a very bad way of doing it, is the way you have unintentionally done it here: By repeatedly calling `midiPlayer.start();` inside your loop. ;-)

```
public void start() {
  try {
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/a.mid");
    midiPlayer = Manager.createPlayer(is, "audio/midi");
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }
  z = true;
  Thread t = new Thread(this);
  t.start();
}

public void stop() {
  z = false;
}

public void run() {
  Graphics g = getGraphics();
  midiPlayer.start();
  while (z) {
    draw(g);
    inputKey();
    try {
      Thread.sleep(200);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    };
  }
}
```

More useful info about playing music with JavaME here:
http://www.indiegamemusic.com/help.php?id=1

Comment: Yes. I added setLoopCount(1) for playing once.End removed midiPlayer.start from loop.

Comment: You don't need `setLoopCount()` at all, if you only want to play the music file once.